# Checking for pattern in string Python

Tags: python, string, parsing

Suppose we have strings of the type:

```
test= '--a-kbb-:xx---xtx:-----x--:---g-x--:-----x--:------X-:XXn-tt-X:l--f--O-'
```

that is, they are always composed of 8 sections separated by `:`, so one could split the string into a list with each element corresponding to a section:

```
testsep = test.split(':')
```

giving

```
['--a-kbb-', 'xx---xtx', '-----x--', '---g-x--', '-----x--', '------X-', 'XXn-tt-X', 'l--f--O-']
```

Now I want to check if the string `test` is such that there are in 3 consecutive sections an `x` occurring at the same position of the section. For example, with the `test` given above, we find at least one such case: counting from 1, sections 2,3 and 4 contain an `x` at the same position, namely at index 6. Therefore, our test string here matches the wanted pattern.

- Is there a simple (maybe functional way) of checking for such patterns given strings always composed with the formatting above?

*The naive approach would be to split, then loop through all sections and see if there are consecutive sections having `x` at each possible position (first index 1, 2, ...up to 8), but that wouldn't be very python-like.*

Comment: Have you thought about using regex? Is the pattern already known or do you need to identify the pattern as well?

Comment: You could turn your string into a matrix with 1 in place of 'x' and 0 elsewhere; then sum by column and check if any sum is equal or greater than 3

Comment: @Don ah, so neat, thanks! Feel free to also add that as an answer for future readers.

Comment: Thanks. Have a look on my answer for an alternative solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possibility is to use `itertools.groupby` with a `class` to group runs of strings that all have an `x` at the same position:

```
from itertools import groupby
class X:
  def __init__(self, _x):
    self.x = _x
  def __eq__(self, _val):
    return any(a == 'x' and b =='x' for a, b in zip(self.x, _val.x))

d = ['--a-kbb-', 'xx---xtx', '-----x--', '---g-x--', '-----x--', '------X-', 'XXn-tt-X', 'l--f--O-']
result = [[a, [i.x for i in b]] for a, b in groupby(list(map(X, d)))]
final_result = [b for _, b in result if any(all(h == 'x' for h in c) for c in zip(*b))]
```

Output:

```
[['xx---xtx', '-----x--', '---g-x--', '-----x--']]
```

However, it is much simpler to use the naive approach and indeed, the solution is quite Pythonic:

```
def group(d):
  start = [d[0]]
  for i in d[1:]:
    if any(all('x' == c for c in b) for b in zip(*(start+[i]))):
       start.append(i)
    else:
       if len(start) > 1:
         yield start
       start = [i]

print(list(group(d)))
```

Output:

```
[['xx---xtx', '-----x--', '---g-x--', '-----x--']]
```

Comment: Hi Ajax, hope you are well. I was wondering, if time allows, if you could have a look at this recent post (somewhat related): https://stackoverflow.com/q/64106974/7685268 any feedback would be helpful. Thanks in any case

Answer (score 2):

Is this pythonish enough?

```
str = '--a-kbb-:xx---xtx:-----x--:---g-x--:-----x--:------X-:XXn-tt-X:l--f--O-'
sections = str.split (':')
reduce (lambda a, b: a | ('xxx' in b), [reduce(lambda c, d: c + d, map(lambda c: c[i], sections), '') for i in range(reduce (lambda e, f: max (e, len (f)), sections, 0))], False)
```

**Explanation**

```
reduce (lambda e, f: max (e, len (f)), sections, 0)
```

calculates the maximum section length;

```
for i in range(reduce (lambda e, f: max (e, len (f)), sections, 0))
```

iterates `i` from zero to maximum section length minus 1;

```
map(lambda c: c[i], sections)
```

calculates list of i-th characters of all sections;

```
reduce(lambda c, d: c + d, map(lambda c: c[i], sections), '')
```

calculates string consisting of i-th characters of all sections;

```
[reduce(lambda c, d: c + d, map(lambda c: c[i], sections), '') for i in range(reduce (lambda e, f: max (e, len (f)), sections, 0))]
```

calculates list of strings, where i-th string consists of i-th characters of all sections;

and final expression returns `True` in case any of the strings in the list calculated at previous step contains three consecutive 'x's.

Answer (score 2):

Pick every 9th element and check if there are 3 consecutive 'x's:

```
test= '--a-kbb-:xx---xtx:-----x--:---g-x--:-----x--:------X-:XXn-tt-X:l--f--O-'
for i in range(9):
    if 'xxx' in test[i::9]:
        print("Pattern matched at position %d" % i)
        break
else:
    print("Pattern not matched")
```

gives

```
Pattern matched at position 5
```

Short version:

```
>>> any(('xxx' in test[i::9] for i in range(9)))
True
```